# Why can I execute a = *ary.flatten but not simply *ary.flatten?

Tags: ruby

```
ary = = [[4, 8], [15, 16], [23, 42]]
```

In irb, why can I execute

```
a = *ary.flatten  # => [4,8,15,16,23,42]
```

but not simply

```
*ary.flatten
```

which gives me an error:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):97: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting '='
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I could also execute

```
a,b,c,d,e,f = *ary.flatten
```

without a problem, and the returned value after I press enter is

```
=> [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
```

with a,b,c,d,e,f being now of class Fixnum.

So, what does

```
*ary.flatten
```

return after all? Seems like it should return the individual elements of ary (what exactly is this object it returns?), that I can assign to something: either a (which somehow automatically becomes an Array) or separate individual variables a,b,c,d,e,f each of which is now a Fixnum.

Also,

```
a = *ary.flatten.class  # => [Array]
b = ary.flatten.class   # => Array
```

What is the difference between [Array] and Array? (perhaps I should make this a separate question but I can only post every 90min and I want to know now!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The splat transforms an array into a list of objects as if you had written them out explicitly using commas. So, obviously, it can only be used where such a list of objects can be used.

```
a = 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42
```

is legal, it's a parallel assignment.

```
4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42
```

is not legal, it's a `SyntaxError`.

> So, what does
>
> ```
> *ary.flatten
> ```
>
> return after all? Seems like it should return the individual elements of ary (what exactly is this object it returns?),

It doesn't return an object. It is a syntactic construct that allows you to take an array and use it as if you had written out the elements by hand one-by-one.

> ```
> a = *ary.flatten.class  # => [Array]
> b = ary.flatten.class   # => Array
> ```
>
> What is the difference between [Array] and Array?

`Array` is a class, `[Array]` is an array with a single element, which is the class `Array`.

Comment: Got it, but still confused about the following:
a = *ary.flatten  # => [4,8,15,16,23,42]
b = ary.flatten   # => [4,8,15,16,23,42]
So how come there is a difference in class, and how come one of them (variable a) is an Array of Array, when it doesn't look like it from the output above.

Comment: It's because `a = *ary.flatten` is equivalent to `a.=(*ary.flatten)` which flattens your array in the argument and wraps the elements in a final array given the spat operator.

Comment: @evianpring: I don't understand what you mean. First off, variables aren't anything. They don't have a class. Only objects have classes. Variables point to objects. `a` points to an array with a single element which is the class `Array`, `b` points to the class `Array`. There are no arrays-of-arrays here.

Comment: I understand now what I was missing. I thought that in a = *ary.flatten.class, class would be applied to *ary.flatten. Actually * is applied to ary.flatten.class, so that the object Class is then coerced into an Array, so I get an Array with a Class object in it. In b = ary.flatten.class, class is applied to ary.flatten, so I just get the class object Array.

Comment: @evianpring: Ah, now I understand your question :-D Yes, it's `(a = (*(array.flatten.class)))`. The `.` operator binds really tight, the tightest of all operators.